# Adding two functions to 1 m-file, while making variables in the two functions accessible to both?

Tags: matlab, function, nested

I have 2 Matlab functions that I want to combine into 1 *m file*. The first function `F1` needs data from the second function `F2`. The second function uses `F1` to perform the calculations. How do I combine `F1` and `F2` such that variables in both functions are accessible/recognized by the two functions?

I don't want to redefine variables that are needed by `F2`, when they are already there in `F1`.

The two functions are something like this:

%The first function

```
function [ ] = F1 [....,A1,A2]
(1) calculations based on the data in A1 and A2 
%Two matrices that are imported from a text file into F2
(2) Formulas that use the results in (1)
end
```

%The second function

```
function [ ] = F2 
(1) A1 and A2 imported 
(2) for loop that calls F1 to perform the calculations end
```

Note: I might need to utilize `F1`, but not `F2` in other functions later on. 
`F2` is only needed by `F1`.

Any suggestions on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Improved notation and tags

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a [nested function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)

Comment: I tried to do so, but was asked to redefine some variables that are already existing in the first function. So any advice on the structure?

Comment: You'll need to show some actual code in your question to get any real specific help on the structure

Answer (score 0):

You could use global variable to make sure you don't have to redefine variables. Mathwork makes a good explanation.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html

```
function [a3]=F1(a1,a2)
global a1
%something including F2
end

function F2(a3,a1)
global a1 %A change to a1  will also affect it in F1
%something including F1
else
```